# How can I render an RGB bitmap into a GLKView using 2D textures?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl

I have an in-memory "bitmap" which is just a malloced `Byte *` array that contains pixel data in a simple RGB format (so the size of the byte array is 3 * the number of pixels).

My app is just a view controller with an instance of `GLKView`. I have implemented its delegate like so:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

and as expected this sets the background color of the GLKView.

What I would now like to do is add code to this implementation of `glkView:drawInRect:` so that my "bitmap" is rendered into this GLKView. But I can't seem to find any way of doing that simply; I'm kind of overwhelmed by all the different things OpenGL can do, all of which are much more complex than what I'm trying to do here.

`glReadPixels` seems to sort of be what I'm after here as it seems to provide a pointer to the buffer data.

**Edit:** apparently this can only be accomplished via the use of textures. I have attempted to implement this with this sample code (note that my "bitmap" here is 4 bytes per sample, matching the format parameters):

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // raw data
    int width = 30;
    int height = 30;
    int pixelCount = width * height;
    int byteSize = pixelCount * 4;
    GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)malloc(byteSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < byteSize; i++) {
        textureData[i] = 255; // white
    }

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLuint textureID;
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, 
        GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    free(textureData);

}
```

... **but it is not working**. The `glClear()` call works as expected and sets the entire background red; but if I understand the texture samples correctly, the code below that should be drawing a 30x30 white square in the corner, but all I'm getting is the solid red background.

Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: that is what I need, but it's not available in iOS, unfortunately.

Comment: You allocate data for texture and pass it to gpu, but that's all. You are not using it. You have to draw a quad and sample the texture in fragment shader.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa: could you link to some samples of this? Every sample I've found online so far just has some variant of what I posted here.

Comment: @MusiGenesis http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Textures https://open.gl/textures - you can skip beginnings cause they are about configuring and creating textures tl;dr you have to create, compile and link shaders, create and fill buffers for your quad and then draw this using `glDrawElements'

Comment: @AdrianKrupa: I do see that overall this is an extremely complicated process, and I was hoping to find a full example somewhere of the relatively simple thing I'm trying to accomplish. I am only doing this at the moment because I am trying to do something equivalent to 'bitblt' in the Windows world (where an arbitrary byte array in memory representing bitmap data can be near-instantaneously copied to the screen). I don't need all the vast complexity that OpenGL offers; I basically have a 200 x 200 (pt) `UIView` and a 400 x 400 x 3 byte array, and I am trying to render that byte array into ...

Comment: ... the UIView in as little time as possible. I'm hoping that OpenGL can accomplish this, but at the moment I don't have the time or energy to learn OpenGL principles well enough to figure out how to do this myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about pushing into OpenGL :)

I would create `CGImage` and then `UIImage`

```
void *baseAddress = & textureData;
size_t bytesPerRow = width * 4;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

and then draw it with [drawInRect:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/drawInRect:)

### Edit:

Here is code I've written. This is not production code: it lacks checking for openGL errors, some minor leaks and have global variables but it's good place to enhance it.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

GLuint tex;
float vertices[] = {
    //  Position    Texcoords
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
    1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
    -1.0, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
};

const char * vertexShader = "attribute vec2 position;\n"
                            "attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;\n"
                            "varying vec2 TexCoordOut;\n"
                            "void main() {\n"
                                "gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
                                "TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;\n"
                            "}\n";

const char * fragmentShader =   "precision mediump float;\n"
                                "varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;\n"
                                "uniform sampler2D Texture;\n"
                                "void main() {\n"
                                    "gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);\n"
                                "}\n";

GLuint shaderProgram;
GLuint vao;
GLuint vbo;

-(void) initOpenGLObjects {
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(vao);
    
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    
    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertexShader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);
    
    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    
    char buffer[512];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vs, 512, NULL, buffer);
    
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragmentShader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);
    
    glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    
    glGetShaderInfoLog(fs, 512, NULL, buffer);
    
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vs);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fs);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "TexCoordIn");
    
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo); // Generate 1 buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(float), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(float), (void*)(2*sizeof(float)));
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
}


-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.glkView.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:
                           kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.glkView.context];
    
    CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update)];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    self.glkView.delegate = self;
    [self initOpenGLObjects];
}

- (void)update
{
    [self.glkView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    int width = 300;
    int height = 300;
    int pixelCount = width * height;
    int byteSize = pixelCount * 4;
    GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)malloc(byteSize);
    static int time = 0;
    time = (time+1)%256;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < byteSize; i+=4) {
        textureData[i] = 255;
        textureData[i+1] = time;
        textureData[i+2] = 255;
        textureData[i+3] = 255;
    }
    
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
                 GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);
    
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    
    free(textureData);
}

@end
```

I don't know how do you want to update data, maybe you don't have to malloc/free it every time and just do small changes and update it with `glTexSubImage2D`. Most of the time is spend on filling data.

This code worked on my MacBook with Xcode 7 in simulators and iPhone 6 with iOS 9.0.2.

Comment: Well, I'm already doing that approach, essentially. I'm creating a `CGDataProvider` with my bitmap and then a CGImage from that, and then rendering the CGImage with `self.layer.contents = myCGImage`. For whatever reason, this is slightly faster than the `drawInRect:` approach even though I think they're doing the same thing under the hood. The problem is that I'm using this for animation at 60 fps and it's running my CPU to 60%, which is because the CGImage is actually a new bitmap in memory (and a pretty large one). I'm hoping that OpenGL will let me offload some of this load to the GPU.

Comment: Ok, I'll write copy paste solution for OpenGL, but I cannot test it now so you have to wait till tomorrow

Comment: Wow! That would be very cool, thank you. I was going to offer a bonus for this question and I'll be sure to do that anyway.

Comment: @MusiGenesis done, if you have more questions fell free to ask

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I will try this out tonight when I get home.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! I feel 200% vindicated in my decision to not try and figure this out myself. It even works with 3 bytes per pixel and `GL_RGB` which is mainly what I was worried about. I'm not worried about the globals as they're perfect for what I'll be using this for, but where would I need to watch for OpenGL errors and leaks?

Comment: The way I will be using this, I will just have one instance of `textureData` in memory. When I need to update the frame, I assume all I need to do is to `memcpy` my latest bitmap into `textureData` and then call glSubImage2D, glUseProgram and glDrawArrays? Or do I only have to call glSubImage2D in that scenario?

Comment: Some resources are not freed when creating shaders. Shaders after linking into program can be deleted. glUseProgram is redundant if you only draw here, it has to be call only once, so glSubImage2D or glImage2D, test which works better, and then glDrawArrays

Comment: Hey, I'm undoing the selected answer so I can post a bounty for this question. I'll reselect it once it's eligible.

Comment: So, I've implemented this approach in my animation engine as a replacement for using a CGDataProvider to create a CGImage, and it works but it's slower than my original approach (CGDataProvider puts the CPU as 55-60% and this OpenGL way puts it at 75-85%). I assume I'm doing something wrong here - would you expect the CPU to be working that hard if you were running animation at 60 fps where each frame is 400 x 400 pixels (not points)? This is running on a 5th gen iPod, by the way.